# Как мне найти и удалить определенную строку из txt файла? Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно найти 4 строчку в txt документе и удалить ее, при этом не оставив пустых строк. Как это сделать? Прошу не писать сложный код, мне просто надо удалить определенную строку из файла.

Comment: Вы пытались сами реализовать данный функционал? с чем конкретно возникли сложности?

Comment: а ос и файловая система какая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаление строки можно сделать не вычитывая файл в память целиком. Но перезаписать его всё равно придется полностью:

```
with open('/tmp/test','r') as fr, open('/tmp/test','r+') as fw:
    fw.writelines(line for i,line in enumerate(fr) if i!=3)
    fw.truncate()
```

Можно не переписывать начало, промотаем файл к концу строчки перед ненужной:

```
with open('/tmp/test','r') as fr, open('/tmp/test','r+') as fw:
    for i,line in enumerate(fr):
        if i==(3-1):
            fw.seek(fr.tell())
        elif i>3:
            fw.write(line)
    fw.truncate()
```

Comment: `fr`, `fw` делят общий файл на диске. Как получается что запись не портит чтение?

Comment: Запись опаздывает на одну строчку.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой скрипт:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f_in:
    lines = f_in.readlines()
    f_in.seek(0)
    f_in.writelines(line for ind, line in enumerate(lines) if line.strip() and ind != 3)
    f_in.truncate()
```

Вместо `input.txt` поставьте путь к вашему файлу (если он у вас в той же директории, достаточно названия)

Answer (score 1):

- открыть файл на чтение
- прочитать строки в список через `readlines`
- закрыть файл
- удалить не нужную строку из списка
- открыть файл на запись
- записать список строк в файл через `writelines`
- закрыть файл

Comment: прочитать строки в список через readlines - не надо так....

Comment: @eri Для учебных целей норм. Для боевых понятно надо по-другому делать, не читая весь файл в память.